# SQL query to see changes in user types

Tags: sql, where-in

In an [order] table, some rows have the same user_id but different fee, meaning that they switched from basic to premium over time, or vice versa. Basic pays zero fee, and premium can choose different monthly subscription plans.

I am trying to see the number of users switch from one plan to another. I used the below query to see 'number of basic users'. Is there a way to somehow integrate 'where fee = 0' and 'where fee >0' for same user?

If not, what SQL statement should I use to pull these numbers?

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from orders
where fee = 0 
and date::date > '2013-03-01'::date
```

[image: order]

Comment: you can add an OR condition in the where clause to add fee > 0. that should work.

Comment: This query can be tricky) Is user from sample data with ID 2 should be counted as switch user as he has 2 records but with 0 fee?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) What output do you want?  I don't get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways I can think of. No idea which one is more efficient.

Using subqueries:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from orders
where
  user_id in (select user_id from orders where fee = 0) and
  user_id in (select user_id from orders where fee > 0);
```

Inlining one of the conditions:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from orders
where
  fee = 0 and
  user_id in (select user_id from orders where fee > 0);
```

Using a correlated subquery:

```
select count(distinct user_id)
from orders o1
where
  fee = 0 and
  exists (select * from orders o2 where o1.user_id = o2.user_id and o2.fee > 0);
```

Using a self join:

```
select count(distinct o1.user_id)
from orders o1
join orders o2 on o1.user_id = o2.user_id
where
  o1.fee = 0 and
  o2.fee > 0;
```